# Rails 3 JQuery Mobile Form Submission

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a mobile version of my rails app using jquery mobile.  I have included the following in a js file:

```
 $(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
$.extend(  $.mobile , {
    ajaxEnabled: false
});
});
```

The problem I am having is that if I try to log in (using devise) I am redirected to the create view for the session.

If I click log in with no information entered it seems just text with an error is rendered to the screen.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Make-Devise-work-with-other-formats-like-mobile,-iphone-and-ipad-%28Rails-specific%29

In the end it came down to the following:

Devise Initializer

config.navigational_formats = [:html, :mobile]

Action Controller initializer:

ActionController::Responder.class_eval do
  alias :to_mobile :to_html
end

Jquery:

$(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
    $.extend(  $.mobile , {
        ajaxEnabled: false,
    });
});